Tables + SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]
When I use this code to create data:
tuples = Tuples[{0, 1}, 31];
x[i_][n_] := tuples[[n]][[i]];

I get this message:
SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]

Why and what is the solution.
Thanks for the help

tuples contains $2^{31}$ elements. Each of them takes approximately 168 bytes in the memory. This means you are trying to put ~390 GB of data in your memory (RAM). Do you have such large memory? It seems not, therefore the error message :) The solution is to [edit] your question and explain what your actual problem is. Then we can give you a meaningful solution. Alternatively, take a look at lazy tuples, which have been mentioned several times on this SE.

@Domen You explained the reason in detail in your comment. I used case $2^{27}$ and it worked but when it is $2^{31}$ the message appears. The reason seems to be memory.

Because the variable tuples weights more than 770 GB.
Consider
dat = {#, Log@N@ByteCount[Tuples[{0, 1}, #]]} & /@ Range[20];
fit = LinearModelFit[dat, x, x];

Then, we can estimate the size of Tuples[{0,1},31] as follows:
In[74]:= UnitConvert[Quantity[Exp[fit["BestFit"]/.x->31],"Bytes"],"Gigabytes"]
Out[74]= 770.537GB


Thank you very much this answer helped me understand the problem
